# KeyStoreException Access is Denied

Tags: java, keystore

I am trying to add my self sign certificate to Window trust Store.

```
KeyStore root = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
root.load(null,null);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("mycer.cer");
X509Certificate cacert =     (X509Certificate)CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(in)    ;
root.setCertificateEntry("selfsignedcert", cacert);
```

But I get this exception.

> java.security.KeyStoreException: Access is denied.

Any thoughts how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Does file ```mycer.cer``` exist? Do you have write persmission in folder?

Comment: Did you supply the right password? Which line threw the exception? Where is the stack trace that should have accompanied this question?

Comment: @user996142 yes mycer.cer file exists.

Comment: @EJP why need to supply the password. The exception comes in the line       root.setCertificateEntry("selfsignedcert", cacert);. The same code works in one window system but not working in another window system. So not able to get any clue why it is happening. I suspect might be some kind of authentications/privileges is not there in the machine where it does not work. But not able to trace what needs to be fixed in that machine so that it will work.

Comment: This exception does not come if I logged in my account as Administrator. It seems the problem was there with authentication. Anyway thanks guys for your comments.

Comment: @user3751824 I'm facing the same issue. Do you have any update about this issue?